# Exposing a Wolfram dataset using CloudDeploy

Tags: wolfram-cloud, cloud-deploy

Base function:

```
beta = Function[{x}, y = ResourceData[ResourceObject[x]]]
```

Then I deploy this using `CloudDeploy`:

```
CloudDeploy[APIFunction[{"x" -> "String" }, beta[#x] &]] ;
```

which returns a URL. but when I try to pass params to it ny adding `?x="Meteorite Landings"` in front of the link, I get a `$Failed` error

Also, how would I grab the dataset in `json` format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
beta = APIFunction[{"tablename" -> "String"},ResourceData[ResourceObject[#tablename] ]& ]
co = CloudDeploy[beta, Permissions->"Public"]
```

for some reason it requires public permissions